# Get row number for repeated sets of categories

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like:

```
id   |    cat
-----+------------
1    |    A
2    |    A
3    |    B
4    |    B
5    |    A
6    |    A
7    |    B
8    |    A
9    |    B
10   |    B
```

I want a row number that group the sets by category but increments by sets, like:

```
id   |    cat     |   row_number
-----+------------+-------------
1    |    A       |   1
2    |    A       |   1
3    |    B       |   2
4    |    B       |   2
5    |    A       |   3
6    |    A       |   3
7    |    B       |   4
8    |    A       |   5
9    |    B       |   6
10   |    B       |   6
```

I've tried using window functions, but the "partition by" resets for every category.

```
SELECT *, row_number() over(PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY id)
from data order by id
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can phrase this as a gaps and islands problem, and then use `DENSE_RANK()`;

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY id) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY cat, rn1 - rn2) AS min_id
    FROM cte
)

SELECT id, cat, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY min_id) AS row_number
FROM cte2
ORDER BY id;
```

The first CTE finds all islands as defined by groups of records having the same `cat` value in the same `id` sequence.  The second CTE assigns the minimum `id` value to each record.  Finally, in the outer query, we use `DENSE_RANK` with this minimum id to generate the desired sequence.